# Interpretation of Differentials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

$$
\newcommand{\qa}{P}
\newcommand{\qb}{Q}
\newcommand{\da}{dP}
\newcommand{\db}{dQ}
\newcommand{\positiverealnumbers}{\mathbb{R}_+}
\newcommand{\realnumbers}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\naturalnumbers}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\positiveintegers}{\mathbb{Z}_+}
$$

We frequently solve geometrical and physical problems by obtaining an
approximate expression for differential $\da$ in terms of differential
$\db$ and then integrating $\da$ to obtain $\qa$. We assume that the
expression for $\qa$ is exact even though we used an approximate
formula for $\da$. This is justified by saying that the differentials
are infinitely small quantities. For example, when we derive an
expression for the area of a circular disc (see example 1) we set
$dA = 2 \pi r dr$ which is an approximate expression when the
diffentials are interpreted as real numbers. In this article we try to
define a method for computing $\qa$ so that we don't need approximate
expressions in the derivation.

**Theorem 1**

Let $a,b \in \realnumbers$ and $a < b$.
Let $f$ be a function from $[a,b]$ into $\realnumbers$ and define
$\Delta f = f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)$
where
$x \in \realnumbers$ and $\Delta x \in \realnumbers \backslash \{0\}$
and $x, x + \Delta x \in [a, b]$.
Suppose that
$$
  \Delta f = g(x) \Delta x + h(x, \Delta x)
  $$
where $x$ and $\Delta x$ are defined as before.
Suppose also that $g$ is Riemann integrable and
$$
    \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{h(x,\Delta x)}{\Delta x} = 0
  $$
for all $x \in [a, b]$.

Now
$df = g(x) dx$ and
$$ f(x) - f(a) = \int_a^x g(t) dt . $$

*Proof*

This is a direct consequence of the definition of differentiability
and Fundamental Theory of Calculus.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

The condition (1) can be weakened to
$$
  \lim_{\Delta x \to 0+} \frac{h(x, \Delta x)}{\Delta x} = 0 .
  \tag{2}
$$

**Theorem 2**

A sufficient condition for inequality (2) is that there
exist $S, C \in \positiverealnumbers$ so that
$$
  \vert h(x, \Delta x) \vert < C \vert \Delta x \vert^2
  $$
for all $x, x + \Delta x \in [a, b]$ and
$0 < \Delta x < S$.

*Proof*

$$
  \left\vert \frac{h(x, \Delta x)}{\Delta x} \right\vert
  < C \vert \Delta x \vert \to 0
  $$
as $\Delta x \to 0+$.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

**Example 1**

Derive an expression for the area of a disc whose inner radius is $r_a$ and outer radius $r_b$.

[The area to be computed in example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRaHf.png)

*Solution*

Define $\Delta A$ to be the area of a disc with inner radius $r$ and
width $\Delta r$.
We have
$$
2 \pi r \Delta r \leq \Delta A \leq 2 \pi (r + \Delta r) \Delta r
$$
By setting
$g(r) := 2 \pi r$ and $h(r, \Delta r) := 2 \pi (\Delta r)^2$ we get
$A = \pi r_b^2 - \pi r_a^2$ by Theorems 1 and 2.

**Example 2**

Suppose that a particle is moving under influence of a constant force
$F = ma$ for time $T$ and the particle is initially at rest. Derive
an expression for the kinetic energy of the
particle. Assume that the work done by a constant force $F$ is
$W = F s$ where $s$ is the distance that the particle moves in the
direction of the force. Assume also that the kinetic energy of a
particle at rest is $0$.

*Solution*

We define $\Delta s$ to be the distance that the particle moves in the
time interval $[t, t + \Delta t]$.
We have $v = at$,
$$
a t \Delta t \leq \Delta s \leq a (t + \Delta t) \Delta t ,
$$
and
$$
a (t + \Delta t) \Delta t = a t \Delta t + a (\Delta t)^2 .
$$
Set $g(t) := a t$ and $h(t, \Delta t) := a (\Delta t)^2$
and it follows from Theorems 1 and 2 that the distance that the
particle moves in time $T$ is
$$
s  = \int_0^T a t dt = \frac{1}{2} a T^2
$$
By setting $v_f = a T$ we obtain
$$
E_k = W = \frac{1}{2} F a T^2 = \frac{1}{2} m a^2 T^2
= \frac{1}{2} m v_f^2 .
$$

*Alternative Solution*

Assume that the particle moves distance $\Delta s$ in time $\Delta
t$. Define $\Delta W := F \Delta s$. Now the acceleration $a =
\Delta v / \Delta t$ is a constant and we have
$$
  \Delta W = m a \Delta s = m \Delta v \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}
  \tag{2}
$$
Let $v_{\mathrm{min}}$ and $v_{\mathrm{max}}$ be the minimum and
maximum velocities of the particle. We now have
$$
  v_{\mathrm{min}} \leq \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} \leq
  v_{\mathrm{max}} .
$$
If $\Delta v \geq 0$ we get
$$
  m v_{\mathrm{min}} \Delta v \leq \Delta W \leq m v_{\mathrm{max}}
  \Delta v ,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
  m v \Delta v \leq \Delta W \leq m (v + \Delta v) \Delta v .
$$
If $\Delta v < 0$ we have
$$
  v + \Delta v \leq \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} \leq v ,
$$
from which it follows that
$$
  m v \Delta v \leq \Delta W \leq m (v + \Delta v) \Delta v .
$$
Define
$$
  h(v, \Delta v) := \Delta W - m v \Delta v .
$$
Now
$$
  0 \leq h(v, \Delta v) \leq m \Delta v^2 .
$$
By setting $g(v) = m v$ and assuming that the kinetic energy is zero
when $v = 0$ it follows from Theorems 1 and 2 that
$$
  E_k = W = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 .
$$

---

Do you find this formalism useful?

Tommi Höynälänmaa

Comment: I'm curious about the `\newcommand`s you have in the beginning of your post. Do you really find it more convenient to type `\qa` than to type `P`? And is `\Bbb R_+` (or even `\mathbb R_+`) actually simplified by `\positiverealnumbers`?

Comment: I view $d$ as an operator, almost the same as $\frac{d}{dx}$. Both operations act on functions, and the resulting $df$  and $\frac{d}{dx}f$ are also functions. $df := \frac{d}{dx}f \Delta x$. So the definition of $df$ requires you to know what $\frac{d}{dx}f$ means. The two are essentially the same operation. There is one function where the differential of it, is just an increment. consider $g: x \mapsto x$, then $dg = 1 \Delta x$. When you see $\Delta x$, it's often written as $dx$ . Or independent variable $\Delta r$ often as $dr$. When you turn the increment of an independent variable

Comment: into a differential like $dx$ or $dr$, you are viewing the independent variable as an identity function (you can only apply $d$ to functions). $\int$ means anti-derivative, it can also mean anti-differential. That's how I view differentials. I don't add anything new to it besides what a derivative is (though it still is slightly different: tangent height as opposed to tangent slope)

Answer (score 1):

I am not finding anything quite new in your formalism to bypass the use of differentials , in the realm of standard analysis.

As for the applicability of theorem 1 in example 1, the formal definition of area in a plane it can be proven quite formally (For reference see Apostol calculus volume 1 the very first chapter on integral calulus), so it seems nothing new.

For the application in example 2, **What are taking the formal definition of work?** that your assuming **monotonicity** in the very first inequality appearing in the solution of example 2 ? If you are taking somewhat an axiomatic definition of work as given in Apostol Calculus volume 1 chapter on ***Application of Integral calculus*** then the question comes why to remember such set of axioms rather than taking the definition of work as the integral $\large\int_a^{a'} \vec F.d\vec s$ in general, when they are equivalent in the special case of real line?